# How to execute a query from psql without waiting for the result?

Tags: postgresql, psql

My query (to create a new table from existing table) takes a very long time. So I've set up a remote database in my office - more RAM there.

I can connect to my database from home as usual with psql.

How can I tell the remote server to execute my query from the terminal without having to wait for a response?

(postgresql-9.2 , linux enviroment)

**Edit:
I'm open to other solutions, it's not necessary to use psql**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you state that you are open to other solutions I might suggest looking at terminal multiplexers such as [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen) or [tmux](http://tmux.github.io/). In my opinion tmux is a better choice due to its unique name (easier to get relevant hits in search engines).

Essentially this kind of software allows you to detach from a shell and later resume the session.

Comment: Does `tmux` work this way: 'Will I be able to shutdown my local machine, and the query still get proccessed at the remote server' ?

Comment: Yes, the session is running on the remote machine - a power outage or loss of internet connection is a non issue (in regard to the remote session :) ). Note that you need to start the process from within the terminal multiplexer (afaik).

Comment: can you provide guidance of how this is implemented? `psql` is client software thats running on your local machine, then `tmux` is making `ssh` connection to a remote machine running a postgres server?  If that's the case I've sadly realized this won't work with a Redshift instance without an EC2 running as well.

Comment: @Merlin tmux runs on the remote machine and establishes the shell session. It is from this that you detach and attach. When running psql locally you could run it in a tmux session, but the client connection is only kept as long as network conditions allow - just as a normal ssh session.

Comment: @c0dem4gnetic i think psql must still be be installed on the remote server. Seems like local tmux -> EC2 + tmux + psql logging into redshift/postgres db to keep the session alive.

Answer (score 12):

You can try sending `psql` to the background:

```
psql -f your_sql_file.sql &
```

Or, connecting to the local DB, you can use [`dblink`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/dblink.html) to dispatch a query to the remote DB:

```
SELECT dblink_connect('your_connection_name', 'your_connection_string');
SELECT dblink_send_query('your_connection_name', 'your_query');
```

Note that `dblink_send_query` can only send one query at a time.  So, if you want to run multiple SQL statements, this is not your solution.

Or, you can start a `pg_agent` job on the remote server, which requires no manual intervention, therefore the state of your home box has no effect on running your job.  The same can be achieved by setting up a `cron` (or even better, `at` - thanks, Erwin) job executing your script.

Additionally, if you have a long running job which you start manually, you can start a [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) session on the server and run the file from there.  In this case, you can log off and go home, and the script will keep running.

Comment: pg_agent looks promising enough. I will try it and update the results.

Comment: Or, for a one-time operation, the [`at` command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Unix%29) might serve you better than cron.